# Why my iPod touch 4 cannot register APNS?

Tags: ios, ios5, apple-push-notifications, ipod-touch

I am trying to test my app on iPod touch 4, however I need APNS support.

I found out that neither delegate callbacks for APNS is called.

I've searched through the [Technical Note](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html), and it doesn't help (for the same code works for my iPad2, that the device token is returned).

Any idea on this?

I am using iPod touch 4 with iOS 5.1.1

## Edit:

Ah, more information provided here.
I have create a provisioning profile before as well as all those certificates. That's why I can work that out with iPad.

Then today, I just added my iPod touch 4 as the development device and downloaded the provisioning profile again. Will this act not registering my iPod touch 4 to be able for handling APNS job????

## Edit 2:

As requested:

Actually I just do whatever Apple requested me to do,
that I included

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge)];
    //Other codes...
}
```

Then, the two delegates callback methods

```
#pragma mark - For Apple Push Notification Service

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{ 
    NSString *str = [NSString 
                 stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
    NSString *devToken = [[[[str description] 
                           stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""] 
                          stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""] 
                         stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
   NSLog(@"%@", devToken);
   NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (standardUserDefaults)
    {
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:devToken forKey:@"device_token"];
        [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error);
}
```

Actually, I just copy and paste what Apple provided me.
However the case is just as mentioned above, either method is called for iPad2 with iOS 5.0.1, iPhone with iOS 4.3 but not for my iPod Touch 4 with iOS5.1.1.

Comment: I think your best bet is to provide some code so that we can see exactly what you're doing.

Comment: @Luke - I've updated my questions already please have a look : )